# command not found: rbenv when starting a new terminal

Tags: ruby, homebrew, zsh, rbenv, zshrc

I have this line `eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"` in my `.zshrc`. But it's throwing the command not found error for `rbenv` every time I start a new terminal. But `rbenv` works if I type it in manually, it only breaks when I start a new terminal. So in order for me to set a specific version for ruby, I need to run `eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"` manually every time instead of relying on the terminal itself to run it automatically.

PS: I installed rbenv with Homebrew.

Comment: Re: "the command not found error" can you please share the actual error message?

Answer (score 0):

> I have this line eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)" in my .zshrc.

The line should be after the `rbenv` binary location is loaded to the `PATH` environment variable.

Example:

```
export PATH="/home/someusername/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
```